# Android Studio Gradle Sync Error using google play-services-maps 11.6.2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing a google map app using Android Studio.  When I sync the project with Gradle Files (Select Tools/Android/Sync Project with Gradle Files on Android Studio), I get the following error:

Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2.
Couold not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.62./play-services-maps-11.6.2.pom

This is the software I am using:

1. Android Studio 3.0.1
2. Android Version 7.1.1
3. Google Play Services 46
4. Google Repository 58 (under Support Repository)

I've tried using both the google maps project template and the empty activity project but I get the same error.

I am using the http proxy setup I used from earlier projects.  I am able to install the play-services-maps and the google repository.

I also added the maven url to the Gradle Project file in the All Projects/Repositories section.

I have tried the suggestions from Stack Overflow but none have not worked.

Any ideas?

```
Gradle Project Build file:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The gradle app build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hansen.scott.googlemaps"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

The error is in the line:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'

Comment: Did you add this maven url? 


 maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" 
        }

Comment: try to add activity from 1) Right click on your package 2) New 3) google 4) Google maps activity, it will automatically configure all settings and dependencies.

Comment: Please share your build.grable

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I've tried the first two:

Comment: I added the maven url to the Gradle project build file.  I still get the same error.

Comment: I added a google maps activity to my package.  When I sync the files with Gradle, I get the same error.  I tried it again adding the url maven to the Gradle Project build file and received the same result.

Comment: Here is the Gradle Project build file:

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in project level gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I added maven to the project gradle build file.   I still get the same error.

Comment: I've added the Gradle Build Project And app files.

Comment: try adding buildToolsVersion "26.0.2" or latest in app level gradle file. also open sdk manager and update sdk tools.

Comment: I've upgraded to the latest version of the SDK build tools.  I still get the same error when I do a gradle sync.  Sorry but I have no idea how to add the SDK build tool version in the app level file.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had the same issue I did and entered it on Stack Overflow a day or two ago.  The user was getting a build error when using player-services-maps 11.6.2.  If the user changed the version to 11.0.0, the build succeeded.

Once I back-dated the maps version to 11.0.0, this solved my problem too.  I created a new Google Map project and didn't modify the Gradle Build files.

The problem appears to be that play-services-maps won't build using a versions after 11.0.0.  I will post the issue on Github.

Thank you for everybody's help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue for the past one week and posted it on Stack Overflow as well but to no effect.
I have since then figured out the root cause. I am working out of my office and thus have firewalls in place. I got it checked with the system admin and on turning off the firewall the build worked.
So i would advice you to have this checked as well.

Kind regards,
Kabir

Comment: Thank you Kabir.  I'll try that.